# jQuery Autocomplete crashes Google Chrome tab

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery autocomplete.  I use it all the time without problems.  However, in this particular instance, the results are retrieved successfully, but as soon as the options are displayed on the page, the tab crashes completely, with Chrome's dead tab page.

This only happens in Google Chrome.

The problem may, I guess, be unrelated to (but co-incidentally triggered by) the Autocomplete, but in case I am missing something in my Autocomplete code, here it is;

```
content.find(".saleLine input[name='item']").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "q=" + request.term + "&page=0&pageLength=20",
            url: $("input[name='itemSearchUrl']").val(),
            success: function (data) {
                var list = new Array();
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    list[i] = {
                        label: item.Code + ': ' + item.Name,
                        value: item.ID,
                        item: item
                    };
                });
                response(list);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                response(null)
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        var item = ui.item.item;
        var itemSelect = $(this);
        var row = itemSelect.parent().parent();
        itemSelect.hide();
        row.find("td.unit").html(item.Unit);
        var link = $('<a href="#editLine">' + item.Name + '</a>');
        itemSelect.after(link);
    }
});
```

Comment: Which autocompleter and which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery (1.4.2) UI (1.8.11) Autocomplete

Comment: Just happened on my Linux Chrome (37.0.2062.120), but the examples on http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote are working just fine!

Comment: Still go many issues with it. I'm going to switch to https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete, less code, works fine.